# Swipe Aerrow PagerSlidingTabStrip android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, pagertitlestrip

I have got code PagerSlidingTabStrip with **underline** page indication but we need to make swappable arrow indication instead of underline. Here in code PagerSlidingTabStrip  class just passing the color to show indication then how will put own arrow indicator  image in the TAB Menu.

Please suggest appropriate solution.

Thanks

Comment: what is PagerSlidingTabStrip? is it a 3rd party library?

Comment: please show screenshots

Comment: Yes its third party library, see this example https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip